# Floating point vs integer performance

Tags: python, integer, floating-point, double

When developing a programming language, is distinguishing between ints and floats important? I noticed in the case of `R` that while they do allow for strict integer types, one mainly deals with `numeric` types which can be floats or ints. Are there performance benefits?

**Edit**
I'm also interested in learning more about when the time period was (if there was one) where one would notice a difference in performance by choosing a float instead of an integer.

Comment: Are you asking whether floating-point math is as performant as integer math?

Comment: .. or whether the possible loss of precision in floating-point arithmetic has become less important over the years?

Comment: It depends obviously on your use case. Have a look at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization. If that does not solve your problem, use http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html to measure whether it's important or not.

Comment: I'm wondering if I lose in performance by making everything a float (everything that is numerical and not an index).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about performance: For most purposes, there is no performance difference. You can probably still measure one in purely number-crunching code compiled to machine code, and for slightly less math-intense code on hardware that doesn't have a dedicated FPU (i.e. mostly embedded stuff). But for Python (and many other languages), any difference in the hardware's performance is dwarfed (by many many orders of magnitude) by the interpretation and boxing overhead. When number are treated as pointers to 16-byte structures with addition being a dynamically-dispatched method call in response to an interpreted opcode, it doesn't matter if the actual processing takes one nanosecond or hundred.

Semantically, the difference between integers and (approximations of) reals is still and always will be a mathematical fact rather than a necessity that follows from the state of the art of computer engineering. For example, floats (in general, not implicit conversions from floats that are exactly integers) will *never* make sense as indices.